# Asking for the device pincode instead of fingerprint scan

Tags: xcode, fingerprint, biometrics

I want to implement a fingerprint scan, which works. But the fingerprint scanner is not available on all iphone devices. So i need to provide an alternative methode for authentication. I thought the pincode of the device could be asked instead. However I cannot find a way how to prompt this pin code. Is it even possible? Or do I need to ask the user for a pincode the first time they open the app, and then use that one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not all users have pincodes, you probably need to make your own if you need to secure access to the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for this. Many apps implement a pin code screen but that screen is not linked to the device pin. It will be app specific.

Personally I find this a major security issue. Because most people will likely choose the same pin for your app that they use for the device globally. Bad habits. But you can't blame them.

My gut feeling says that many apps do not properly store this pin code in the keychain.

Not sure what to suggest as an alternative.